# Como faço para listar todas os campos de uma tabela mais um valor aleatório de outra tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Estou com um problema ao fazer o relacionamento com duas tabelas, `tb_adm_anuncios` e `tb_adm_anuncio_banner`.

Para cada anúncio eu tenho 4 banners, e para listar esses anúncios eu preciso:

```
**Anúncio:**
-Nome do Anúncio
-Link

**Banner:**
-Imagem
```

O comando que estou usando para fazer isso é esse:

```
SELECT 
anuncios.id AS id_anuncio, 
anuncios.titulo_anuncio, 
banners.id AS id_banner, 
Rand(banners.imagem) AS imagem_banner 
FROM tb_adm_anuncio AS anuncios 
LEFT JOIN tb_adm_anuncio_banner AS banners ON anuncios.id = banners.fk_anuncio AND 
                                              anuncios.status = 1 
GROUP BY banners.fk_anuncio 
limit 12
```

Quando executo esse comando ele não me retorna todos os anúncios, e não sei o motivo.

[image: DIAGRAMA]

Comment: Qual versão do MySQL usa?

Comment: @rray A versão do MYSQL é 5.7.19

Answer (score 1):

veja se lhe atende:

```
SELECT
a.id as id_anuncio,
a.titulo_banner,
(SELECT 
 b.img 
 FROM tb_adm_anuncio_banner b
 WHERE b.fk_anuncio = a.id 
 ORDER BY RAND()
 LIMIT 1
) as imagem_banner
FROM tb_adm_anuncio a
WHERE a.status = 1
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Infelizmente não amigo, mas descobri o problema vou publicar agora, obrigado pela tentativa.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, mudei para ele filtrar os GROUP BY usando o anuncios.id ao invés de fk_anuncios.

```
 SELECT anuncios.id AS id_anuncio, anuncios.titulo_anuncio, banners.id AS id_banner, banners.imagem AS imagem_banner 
FROM tb_adm_anuncio AS anuncios 
LEFT JOIN tb_adm_anuncio_banner AS banners 
ON anuncios.id = banners.fk_anuncio AND 
anuncios.status = 1 GROUP BY anuncios.id limit 12;
```